# Distinguishing between ImmutableJS and native JS data structures?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm writing a React component that I intend to make public, and I'd like to have it play nice either with JS arrays/objects, or immutable.js equivalents (Map/List).

What's the best way to identify an Immutable.js Map or List? I don't want to simply use `Array.isArray`, because I *do* want to enforce that it is either an Array or a List, for example.

I could just check for some of the Immutable.js properties, like `_origin` or `__ownerID`, but I don't want to depend on internal APIs that are subject to change in minor versions.

Comment: Perhaps you could go the other way and say what operations you need to perform that require different handling. That way you can handle any kind of object.

Comment: Or just be more explicit in your code and more consistent in object structures. It's better than having to duck-type every time and get 50% of the time wrong.

Comment: @RobG I'm not sure I understand... I will be handling them differently, I just need to identify them first. To give a more concrete example, I'm making a grid component that accepts a 2D Array or List. I need to iterate through it, and so I'll need to know if I can just `arr[x][y]`, or if I have to `arr.getIn([ 'x','y' ])`

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer the idea is I'll be releasing this through NPM. I want to support Immutable.js (because many people use it in redux and I don't want them to need to `.toJS` it), but I also don't want to force _everyone_ to use Immutable. If it was all my own code I could be consistent, but it's not :)

Comment: @JoshuaComeau—you could do `if (typeof arr.getIn == 'function')` then you have an immutable.js List, otherwise assume it's an Array. But then there is [*List.isList()*](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/isList).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would very much recommend the suggestions given by @robg and @joseph-the-dreamer. However, just for the sake of answering your exact need, for every Immutable.Type there is a Immutable.Type.isType() static function which you can use to determine if a given object is of that type.

E.g. [Map docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/isMap) -

```
var im = require("immutable");

if (im.Map.isMap(someObjectWhichMayBeMap)){
    ...
}
```